# Why isn't my program compiling? (in cmd.exe)

Tags: cmd, c++builder

I've just made a program called "firstprog.c" and now I'm in 'cmd.exe'; I'm following instructions that say this:

> "Compile the file by executing the C compiler.  You can do this by running the BCC32 compiler: just type "bcc32 firstprog.c""

I downloaded and installed Bcc32 (borland C++ Compiler), then typed what it told me (bcc32 firstprog.c) in 'cmd.exe'; It came up with this:

> "'bcc32' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

When I type `dir`, it lists the "firstprog.c" program, so that's good. Can someone tell me why it's not compiling? I figure it's because Borland C++ isn't configured or something?

Answer (score 0):

It simply cannot find the bcc32 executable. For this to be found from any directory within the command prompt, its directory will have to be part of the PATH environment variable. Add the appropriate directory to that and you should be good to go.

You will most likely be able to find this under:

> "My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" > "Path"

Make sure to close your command prompt and reopen it once you've added the correct path.